# Converting to Chomsky Normal Form

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computational-complexity, regular-language, context-free-grammar

I am trying to learn how to convert any context free grammar to Chomsky Normal Form. In the example below, I tried to apply Chomsky Normal Form logic, to result in a grammar, where every symbol either produces two symbols, or every symbol produces a terminal.

I am not %100 sure my implementation is correct, and it is important that I understand how to do this, I would appreciate if someone would let me know if I am on the right track.

**Context Free Grammar**

```
S -> ASA | aB
A -> B | S
B -> b | epsilon
```

After converting to:

**Chomsky Normal Form**

```
S-> CA | CB
C -> AS | a | S
B -> b | epsilon
```

Many Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Conversion from Context Free Grammar to Chomsky Normal Form :
(I ll tell you the steps and will also solve the example you asked simultaneously)

Step 1 : Introduce New Non-terminal $S_0$ and make it derive the start variable  which is S

Thus

> $S_0$ -> S
>
> S -> ASA | aB
>
> A -> B | S
>
> B -> b | $\varepsilon$

Step 2 : Eliminate all $\varepsilon$ transitions

THus we need to eliminate B -> $\varepsilon$

For this we must to replace B with $\varepsilon$ in RHS of every production having B

THus we get,

> $S_0$ -> S
>
> S -> ASA | aB | a
>
> A -> B | S | $\varepsilon$
>
> B -> b

Now new $\varepsilon$ transition is introduced which is A -> $\varepsilon$ .. thus we need to eliminate it too

> $S_0$ -> S
>
> S -> ASA | aB | a | SA | AS | S ... Note: S -> S can be ignored
>
> A -> B | S
>
> B -> b

Step 3 : Eliminate all Unit transitions i.e. those productions having exactly one non-terminal in RHS .

thus we need to eliminate A -> B , A->S ,$S_0$ -> S

THus,first removing A-> B

> $S_0$ -> S
>
> S -> ASA | aB | a | SA | AS
>
> A -> b | S
>
> B -> b

NOw removing A-> S

> $S_0$ -> S
>
> S -> ASA | aB | a | SA | AS
>
> A -> b |  ASA | aB | a | SA | AS
>
> B -> b

NOw removing $S_0$ -> S

> $S_0$ -> ASA | aB | a | SA | AS
>
> S -> ASA | aB | a | SA | AS
>
> A -> b |  ASA | aB | a | SA | AS
>
> B -> b

Step 4 : Now eliminate all the productions that are non in CNF

> $S_0$ -> AM | NB | a | SA | AS
>
> S -> AM | NB | a | SA | AS
>
> A -> b |  AM | NB | a | SA | AS
>
> B -> b
>
> M -> SA
>
> N-> a

The above CFG is in CNF .

:)

Comment: Thank you for the response, it seems very helpful, however, I am not sure why you added a terminal 'a' to your S symbol on step two, that did not appear in step 1, can you please explain?

Comment: Substituting B=$\varepsilon$  in S-> aB  produces S->a

Comment: this is bcoz a$\varepsilon$ = a

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Also, In step 3 part 1, how come symbol A produces terminal 'b'? and in step 3 part 2, how come A produces so many terminals?

Comment: Step3 Grammar 1 ,Substituting all productions of B (which is B->b) gives us A->b .... This was done bcoz we wanted to eliminate A->B

Comment: Step 3 Grammar 2 , Substituting all productions of S (which were S -> ASA | aB | a | SA | AS ) gives us A ->  ASA | aB | a | SA | AS .... This was done bcoz we wanted to eliminate A->S

Comment: And Ya .. u're WElcome.. ny more doubts..?

Comment: Great explanation! Thanks for clarifying :) Marked as solution.

Comment: Thnks.. n u're Welcome..:)